# How to solve the "too many connection" problem in zookeeper when I want to query too many times in reduce stage?

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

Sorry for my stupid question and thank you in advance.
I need to replace the outputvalue in reduce stage(or map stage). However, it will case too many connection in zookeeper. I don't know how to deal with it.
This is my reduce method:

```
public static class HbaseToHDFSReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text, Text> {
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            HashSet<String> address = new HashSet<>();
            for(Text item :values){
                String city = getDataByRowKey("A1",item.toString());
                address.add(city);
            }
            context.write(key,new Text(String.valueOf(address).replace("\"", "")));
        }
```

This is the query method:

```
public static String getDataByRowKey(String tableName, String rowKey) throws IOException {
        Table table = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf).getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
        Get get = new Get(rowKey.getBytes());
        String data = new String();
        if (!get.isCheckExistenceOnly()) {
            Result result = table.get(get);
            for (Cell cell : result.rawCells()) {
                String colName = Bytes.toString(cell.getQualifierArray(), cell.getQualifierOffset(), cell.getQualifierLength());
                String value = Bytes.toString(cell.getValueArray(), cell.getValueOffset(), cell.getValueLength());
                if (colName.equals(rowKey)) {
                    data = value;
                }
            }
        }
        table.close();
        return data;

    }
```

What should I do to solve it?
Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You created one connection per query, and connection creation is a heavy-weight operation. Maybe you can get a Connection in your reduce method and change
getDataByRowKey(String tableName, String rowKey) to this
getDataByRowKey(Connection connection, String tableName, String rowKey).